How to mount headless App component when RNN is installed
In my RN 0.72.15 app, I want to centralize the management of app-wide fore/background functions (eg. user auth, server handling, google cast).
I want to repurpose the App component for this, without returning any JSX. For the UI components, I'm using RNN 7.35.2. I presumed that it doesn't need to be a Headless JS or a Headless task, since the app-wide functions should also run in the foreground (and React seem to be moving away from Headless JS anyway)

Goal and Request
#1 The goal is to implement a headless component (ie. centralizes functions tied to React lifecycle at a layer higher than the existing root UI components) and mount it in the app build, within the context of RNN.

How to register and mount the App component without relying on a .setRoot?

#2 If it can only be mounted when the App component within a root (ie. App component has to return JSX):

How to structure .setRoot to accommodate the headless component, where the existing root has bottomTabs?
How to persist hook dependencies from the higher layer root for the App component, to the existing root?

Any pointers with some code examples/repo to achieve this would be DEEPLY appreciated.

Trial and Error for #1

I tried using AppRegistry for the App component below and Navigation for registering the other UI components, but no logs returned.
AppRegistry stops mounting the App component when RNN is installed and linked. This is probably due to the mainapplication and mainactivity methods being redefined by RNN.
I tried changing the registration order of App and UI components, modularizing them into separate files, but none of these mounted App as a headless component

//App.js
const App = () => {
  //log from someFunction_A
  useEffect(() => {
    //log from someFunction_B 
    return () => //stop someFunction_B 
  }, []);
  return null;
};

export default App;

//index.js
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);

Navigation.registerComponent('existingComponent', () => existingComponent);
Navigation.setRoot({
  //existingComponent in bottomTabs
})


Trial and Error for #2

I could mount the App component by either separating the roots as below, or adding it as a stack or a bottomTab into the root for existingComponent
But neither pattern seem to be persisting the dependencies from someComponent_C after the root switch.
I tried importing someComponent_C as a function into index.js, registering and setting it directly into the root, but still no dependency persistence

//App.js
const App = () => {
//switch root from the App's to the existingComponent's
  return <someComponent_C/>; //encaps functions like A & B above
};

export default App;

//index.js
Navigation.registerComponent('App', () => App);
Navigation.setRoot({
  //App
})
Navigation.registerComponent('existingComponent ', () => existingComponent );
Navigation.setRoot({
  //existingComponent in bottomTabs
})

More concrete codes
For a better clarity, an app-wide function I want to mount looks something like this.
const HeadlessCastManager = () => {
  //define states and cast client, state
  ...
  // CAST AUTOPLAY LOCAL FILES
  useEffect(() => {
      //return if dependencies are not loaded
      //start server and set origin
      //fetch and set playlist
      // switch to the next track when a track duration runs out

    return () => {
      client.stop();
      stopServer();
      setOrigin('');
    };
  }, [castState]);


  // CAST QUEUE & CONTROL LOAD
  useEffect(() => {
      //return if dependencies are not loaded
      //load cast queue with playlist
      GoogleCast.showExpandedControls();
  }, [castState, origin, playlist]);

  return null;
};

export default HeadlessCastManager;

Env info
Test device: Android 12
Dev OS: macOS 11.7.10
Homebrew: 4.4.8
Shell: version "5.8"
Node: version 20.18.0
Yarn: 1.22.22
npm: version 10.8.2
Watchman: Not Found
CocoaPods: Not Found
SDKs: macOS 12.1
Android SDK: 34 installed via Android Studio
Android Studio: 2023.2 AI-232.10300.40.2321.11567975
Xcode: version 13.2.1/13C100
Java: version 11.0.25
Ruby: version 2.6.10
"@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
react: installed: 18.2.0
react-native: installed: 0.72.15
Android:
hermesEnabled: true
newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
hermesEnabled: Not found
newArchEnabled: Not found
